# Error: 1449, "The user specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist"

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I get the above error when I try to retrieve data or insert data via my app to my database. The proc code is as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_createUser`(
    IN p_name VARCHAR(20),
    IN p_username VARCHAR(20),
    IN p_password VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    if ( select exists (select 1 from tbl_user where user_username = p_username) ) THEN

        select 'Username Exists !!';

    ELSE

        insert into tbl_user
        (
            user_name,
            user_username,
            user_password
        )
        values
        (
            p_name,
            p_username,
            p_password
        );

    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I run the following query in my sqlyog it returns a 1:
`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE USER = 'root');`

I am using XAMPP and Python to make my app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `select host from mysql.user where user = 'root'` return?

Comment: My guess is it's actually `root@%`, not `root@localhost`.

Comment: @Barmar 127.0.0.1,
::1,
localhost

Comment: @Barmar did you mean the change to be in the create definer line?

Comment: I was guessing that it wouldn't return `localhost` in the query. Now I don't understand why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 22):

```
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Check: [MySQL user specified as definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173390/mysql-user-specified-as-definer-does-not-exist) and
[MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: The resolution is just as obscure as the error message, but it works!

Comment: This worked greatly for me. And I tried a lot of other solutions!

Comment: may I know what is the opposite of that command? I want to test something thank you